# how to add one image over other image by program?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, imageview

I am new to Android. i need to add one image over another image dynamically by program. I have already predefined image like "8" and then i want to add image 4 on top of it via program. I need to add image dynamically.

What should i use to achieve this functionality?

[list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVV5V.png)

I tried to achieve this functionality by below code, but that does not work.

[image: list image]

```
LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.card2);

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
 (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)card1.getLayoutParams();
 params.setMargins(0, 30, 0, 0);
 imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

 linearLayout.addView(imageView);
 setContentView(linearLayout);
```

Comment: Try to use relative layout and add one image above other with some shift

Comment: This seems like `StackLayoutManager` of `RecyclerView` Do some research on it .Good luck

Comment: Braz , ADM -- Thanks a lot for comment and suggestions. I will work on your suggestions and update you the result.